# AppDomain unhandled exceptions

Tags: c#, exception, appdomain

There are plenty of topics covering the question. But nevertheless I have a problem.

I load the assembly into new `AppDomain` like this:

```
public void Run()
{
    //There's the problem.
    //As Panos Rontogiannis mentioned the thread is created in default AppDomain
    new Thread(RunApp).Start();
}

private void RunApp()
    try
    {
        AppDomain.CreateDomain("domain name").ExecuteAssembly("path to assembly");
    }
    catch (Exception _e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unhandled Exception.\n" + _e);
    }
}
```

In the Main method of the loaded assembly I subscribe my handler to the `UnhandledException` event:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += handleException;
```

The handler itself:

```
public static void handleException(object a_s, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs a_args)
{
    var _e = (Exception)a_args.ExceptionObject;
    //Static loger class method
    Loger.WriteError(_e.GetType().ToString(), _e.Message, "default solution");
}
```

But wherever the exception is thrown in the loaded assembly the handler doesn't get involved. I only catch exception in the default `AppDomain` (first `try{} catch{}`).

Answer (score 4):

Most probably, the reason you cannot handle the exception in the new `AppDomain` is that it is not thrown from a thread that was created in that `AppDomain`. From the documentation on [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) it is not very straight-forward to see that. The interesting part is the following:

> An exception is unhandled only if the entire stack for the thread has
>   been unwound without finding an applicable exception handler, so the
>   first place the event can be raised is in the application domain where
>   the thread originated.

Now if the thread that executes the code that throws, is created in your main `AppDomain` (like the main thread of a console app), then you should add a handler in the main `AppDomain`. Note though that if the type of the thrown exception is not loaded in the main AppDomain, the Assembly Loader of .NET will try to load it from your applications' base directory and probing paths. If these are not the same with the child `AppDomain`, then the assembly will not be resolved and an(other) exception will be thrown.

Comment: You're right. `ExecuteAssembly` is called in new `Thread` created in default `AppDomain`. But it's crucial to hadle the exceptions inside the assebly loaded in new `AppDomain`

Comment: @Wazelin By handle it, you mean to simply log it. There is not much else you can do with an unhandled exception. The AppDomain is doomed and so is the application if the unhanlded exception is thrown from a thread created in the child AppDomain. If you want to isolate your application from other code, you will need to work with different processes.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of reasons that this might happen.  The event documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx covers quite a bit of this complexity in detail  If nothing there seems applicable, could you please post repro code?

Comment: IMHO **This answer should be a comment**

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the handler is not invoked as the exception is handled. i.e. By the upper try{}catch{}.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realy understand why the handler doesn't get invoked.

I ended up using FirstChanceException instead of UnhandledException in Main method of loaded assembly. Like this:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException +=
    (obj, e) => Loger.WriteError(
        e.Exception.ToString(),
        e.Exception.Message,
        "default solution"
    );
```

Comment: It might suit your cause, but I doubt it. A first chance exception incident is _not_ the same as an unchaught exception. In a nutshell, you will get this event for every exception raised, wether it ends up unhandled by code (catch blocks without a rethrow) or not.

Comment: Well since I use it for logging purposes only, I think it's ok. Exceptions get logged and handlers if they exist keep doing their jobs.

Comment: Yes, but remember that some code (even in the .net framework itself) uses exceptions internally, that neve surface and that might obscure your logging with "bogus" exceptions. Your mileage may vary, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. I haven't thought about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late reply, but this seems to work fine if you ask me (VS2012/.NET 4.5), exception handler needs to be registered before ExecuteAssembly is called of course: (I have a child process that causes an Access Violation by writing to a null ref (unsafe code) just to force a crash and it triggers the HandleException below:

```
public static void HandleException(object a_s, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs a_args)
{
    var _e = (Exception)a_args.ExceptionObject;
    Console.WriteLine(_e.GetType().ToString(), _e.Message, "default solution");
}

public void StarProcessWithinAppDomain(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        // New appdoamin / check exception isolation level 
        AppDomain sandBox = AppDomain.CreateDomain("sandBox");
        try
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += HandleException;
            sandBox.ExecuteAssembly(fileName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred (inner) within AppDomain, executing \"{0}\":" + "\n" + ex.Message, fileName);
        }
        finally
        {
            AppDomain.Unload(sandBox); 
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred within AppDomain, executing \"{0}\":" + "\n" + ex.Message, fileName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `FirstChanceException` fires.
2. Any `catch` blocks are executed.
3. If no `catch` block or `throw` in the block then `UnhandledException` fires

Your `catch` block ensures that `UnhandledException` doesn't fire.